# Visual Studio 2008 C++ Compilation: No Lib file Generated

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to build a C++ project as a dll, the procedure I follow is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Note that during the project creation stage, I specify the DLL instead of static library. My understanding is that by doing so both a `.dll` and a `.lib` will be created.

But after I compile that project, only `.dll` is created, the `.lib` file, on the other hand, is not.

The problem of this is that, when I reference that C++ project in another C++ project ( again, using the same procedure [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)), I got a fatal error lnk1104:

> fatal error LNK1104:cannot open file
>   '..\debug\cgapi.lib'

Anything I miss in my vcproject setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic diagnostic is that you didn't export anything.  You can double-check with Dumpbin.exe /exports on your DLL.

Be sure to decorate the functions you want to export with __declspec(dllexport).  Or use a .def file.